# How can I add a theme template to site?

Tags: theming, 8

Bootstrap has templates like *new age*, *creative*, *clean blog*, etc. How do I add these templates to my site?

My workflow didn't work out well.

- I copied the starter kit *less* to themes/custom
- I renamed it to testtheme
- I renamed all THEMENAME.yml files to testtheme.yml
- I executed `git clone https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-new-age.git`

Edit:
- Installed and set as Default (backend)

Unformatted bootstrap
[image]

```
edit 2:
global-styling:
 ` css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
      css/new-age css: {}
      css/new-age.min css: {}

bootstrap-scripts:
  js:
    js/new-age.js: {}
    js/new-age.min.js: {}
```

[image: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollspy is not a function]

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps to add the bootstrap:

```
1. Put the bootstrap theme in the theme folder.
2. If you want to create a sub theme then copy the cdn folder from starterkits and rename. (themename)
3. Rename .info.yml , .libraries.yml and .theme files with your themename.
```

Include the CSS in theme.libraries.yml file. Like below

```
global-styling:
 css:
  theme:
    css/style.css: {}

global-scripting:
 css:
  theme:
   js/script.js: {}
```

Comment: Hi to use the new age template, do I have to use the cdn or less starterskit? Because the new age Features [link]https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/new-age/
- LESS files included for deeper customization options

Comment: the steps were very usefull